# What is the difference between a set state and a set state with an arrow in react native

Tags: react-native, arrow-functions

I am creating a function that handles some logic from a switch change, but the follow doesn't work, but when I add the arrow part it does, but I don't understand what the arrow is doing in this context????

Underlying logic that is getting triggered to call my function

```
const [verbose, setVerbose] = useState(false)
<Switch
        trackColor={{ false: "#767577", true: "#81b0ff" }}
        thumbColor={isEnabled ? "#f5dd4b" : "#f4f3f4"}
        ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
        onValueChange={userChangedVb}
        value={verbose}
      />
```

What doesn't work:

```
function userChangedVb(vb) {
    //other logic
    setVerbose(!vb )
  }
```

What does work:

```
function userChangedVb(vb) {
    //other logic
    setVerbose(vb => !vb )
  }
```

Can someone explain why? I guess I don't know what the arrow is doing inside the set state call?  I'm still new to react native and usually when I use or see the arrow its something like this () =>  to generate a new function.

EDIT: This is mostly from the example here, which has the expo emulator so its really easy to try/experiment this code: https://reactnative.dev/docs/switch#onchange

EDIT: part of the problem is the vb parameter comming in has already been changed, so if I use:

```
function userChangedVb(vb) {
    //other logic
    setVerbose(vb )
  }
```

It works as intend.

Comment: Here's more on arrow functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions.

Comment: The setState functions expects either a value or a callback. When passed a callback, it has the previous value as parameter.

Comment: @jperl so in this case setVerbose(vb => !vb) is calling setVerbose(vb) and then the arrow is setting vb to !vb after?

Comment: No it's a callback (a function) `(prevValue) => !prevValue`.

Comment: Make sure to read the link I provided (arrow functions).